# No Intersection Area for geographic coordinates with Boost Geometry

Tags: geometry, gis, computational-geometry, boost-geometry

I need to check whether two points (GPS coordinates) `q`, `m` are in the same side or on the opposite side or co linear to a line (great circle segment) `(p,t)`. I know that `q` is not co linear to `(p, t)`. I didn't find and any direct function to use in the boost.geometry library. So I tried to calculate it in a different way.

I construct two triangles `(p, q, t)` and `(p, m, t)`. Then I intersect these two and check the area of the intersection polygon. Following is my code.

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::point<
    double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::spherical_equatorial<boost::geometry::degree>
> geo_point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<geo_point> geo_polygon;

geo_point p(110.48316, 29.05043);
geo_point q(110.48416, 29.05104);
geo_point t(110.48416, 29.05228);
geo_point m(110.48408, 29.05079);

geo_polygon ut, es;

boost::geometry::append(ut.outer(), p);
boost::geometry::append(ut.outer(), q);
boost::geometry::append(ut.outer(), t);
boost::geometry::append(ut.outer(), p);

boost::geometry::append(es.outer(), p);
boost::geometry::append(es.outer(), m);
boost::geometry::append(es.outer(), t);
boost::geometry::append(es.outer(), p);

std::list<geo_point> intersection_points;
boost::geometry::intersection(ut, es, intersection_points);
std::cout << intersection_points.size() << std::endl;

std::vector<geo_polygon> intersection_polygons;
boost::geometry::intersection(ut, es, intersection_polygons);
std::cout << intersection_polygons.size() << std::endl;
```

[Live at cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/9hc3j)

If we plot these two triangles we can clearly see that they intersects on 3 vertices yielding another triangle in the intersected region.

[image]

The above code correctly returns the number of intersected points, but it doesn't return any intersection polygon.

```
3
0
```

I have tried using `geographic` instead of using `spherical_equatorial` coordinate system. But got the same results. Am I missing something ? or this is a problem in `Boost.Geometry`

Comment: What do you want to get from intersection triangle? I don't see how it could help to solve your problem. But calculation of bearings is useful to determine " the same side"

Comment: The intersection polygon is a straight line if they are on the opposite side, so the area will be 0. Otherwise there will be a non zero area.

Comment: OK, it's reasonable. I made an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that polygons are closed and oriented as needed, apply [correct](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/correct.html). Inserting

```
boost::geometry::correct(ut);
boost::geometry::correct(es);
```

[gives](http://cpp.sh/44joe) result **1 polygon** for your test

Comment: The polygons are closed properly because I append that first point at the end. Isn't that sufficient ? Also what does `oriented` mean in this context ?

Comment: From description: `all rings which are wrongly oriented with respect to their expected orientation are reversed` (I was wondering myself)